# "Не" с отглагольными прилагательными и причастиями

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, причастия, нн

**давно не/хожен(н)ая дорога**
**давно не/езжен(н)ая дорога**

Я склоняюсь писать слитно и с одной Н. Так как это не причастия, а прилагательные. Страдательные причастия прошедшего времени образуются только от переходных глаголов. А наличие зависимых слов не влияет на написание прилагательных. Но я снова сомневаюсь.

Comment: Приставка НЕ не изменяет написание прилагательных и причастий: крашеный  (прил.)– некрашеный (прил.), окрашенный (прич.)  – неокрашенный (прич.). Но при наличии зависимых слов отглагольные прилагательные переходят в причастия:  крашеная (прил.)  скамейка – недавно крашенная (прич.)   скамейка, давно не крашенная (прич.) скамейка.
Но вариант «давно не езженый» идет по особой статье, так как ездить – непереходный глагол,  формально от него нельзя образовать страдательное причастие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сомнения понятны (эта тема вызывает много сложностей), а рассуждения верные. Помочь может следующее правило, если оно еще не попадалось.

[Буквы ***нн*** и ***н*** в причастиях и отглагольных прилагательных](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2157) (справочник Розенталя):

> 3. Наличие приставки ***не-*** на написание отглагольного прилагательного не влияет: *неезже**н**ый, нехоже**н**ый, незва**н**ый, непроше**н**ый, некоше**н**ый, некраше**н**ый, некрещё**н**ый, неписа**н**ый (закон), непуга**н**ый.*

*Как глуха и пустынна кажется старая большая дорога, **давно** забытая и **неезженая**!* [И. А. Бунин. Золотое дно (1903)]

*Лежит за Курдайским нагорьем **Веками нехоженый** край...* [Чингиз Айтматов. Верблюжий глаз (1962)]

*Эта **нехоженая** и **неезженая** тропа обрывалась у входа в пещеру...* [Марина Дяченко, Сергей Дяченко. Привратник (1994)]

Comment: Для меня самые непростые темы - н/нн в кратких причастиях и кратких прилагательных и написание НЕ с отглагольными прилагательными и причастиями. Часто путаница возникает. Правила тоже не особо чётко дают разграничения.

Comment: Александр, а "крашеный" в этом предложении Вы бы к какой части речи отнесли? Я купила крашен(н)ую под золото цепочку.

Comment: Интересный случай. Думаю так: *крашенную (как?) под золото*. Зависимые слова придают слову признак действия, значит, причастие.

Comment: А если в этом предложении сделать синонимичную замену? Крашеную под золото = золоченную. Стало быть, здесь будет прилагательное. Купила крашеную золоченную цепочку.  Мозг закипает. Наверное, здесь оба варианты - и мой, и ваш - верны.

Comment: Здесь оба слова написал бы с одной Н. Ни кем *краше**нн**ую*, ни каким способом *золоче**нн**ую* в предложении не обозначено.

Comment:  Все согласны. Это хорошо 

Comment: Ой, почему-то у меня золоченная с двумя н. Хотела с одной написать.

Comment: Александр,  а где же ваша непримиримая критика оппонента, молчите вместе со всеми? Ну, это шутка, я же хотела вот что спросить. У меня появилась такая мысль, что «приличные» писатели (классики, например) вообще избегают таких сочетаний как «давно неезженая дорога». Их любят в основном  составители ЕГЭ, мечтающие «завалить» школьников. Возьмите того же Бунина, у него всё замаскировано, поэтому и красиво: Как глуха и пустынна кажется старая большая дорога, (давно забытая) и неезженая!  Наречие «давно» скорее относится  к «давно забытая», а «нехоженая» прячется в сторонке. Как вы думаете?

Comment: Sharon, конечно, я тоже видел этот разрыв, но оставил пример для общего представления, лучше не попалось. Я отвечал пусть и не сильно "задумчиво", но с верой в то, что вы ответите. Плюс за шурум-бурум в голове :) А как насчет Айтматова: *Веками нехоженый край*?

Comment: Я вообще в Нацкорпусе не нашла ничего, кроме Бунина, хотя ожидала длинный список примеров. Но из меня еще тот искатель. «Веками нехоженый край»  – это значит, что  край оставался в течение многих веков «нехоженым».  Поэтому у Айтматова всё хорошо,  качественный признак. Да это и чувствуется, что красиво. У нас же «давно»  – наречие с  явным временным значением, причем оно перешло  из сочетания  «по дороге давно не ходили», а это признак причастия.

Comment: А вот приведенный в статье пример: «не раз езженой дорогой». Ну какой здесь качественный признак (торная, заросшая  дорога), скорее можно предположить так: не раз езженной (мною) дорогой. Какое-то чисто формальное у них мышление. Это вам в дополнение к «шурум-буруму» в голове от «доброго» друга :)

Answer (score 4):

Никогда не разговаривайте с неизвестными и никогда не отвечайте на вопрос как пишется ***давно(не)езже(нн)ая дорога***. Это "подстава" в чистом виде. Шутка, конечно, да только здесь действительно **много  неясного.**

1. Как вам нравится, примеру,  такое название  статьи «Правило-«убийца», или где теряют баллы на ЕГЭ отличники и призеры олимпиад».

А вот еще одна статья  «Почему «хоженый» и «езженый» пишутся всегда с одним Н, или маленькие хитрости ЕГЭ
https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5ec6ec5b71f6bb078b0d13d8/pochemu-hojenyi-i-ezjenyi-pishutsia-vsegda-s-odnim-n-ili-malenkie-hitrosti-ege-5edab5eaad76dc06c09e866f

«А вот прилагательные ***хоженый, езженый, мудрёный*** и др. даже при наличии зависимых слов пишутся с одной Н: хоженой вчера дорогой, не раз езженой дорогой.
Секрет прост: глаголы «ходить, ездить, мудрить» **непереходные,** следовательно, от них не образуются страдательные причастия.
Поэтому есть только прилагательные ***хоженый, езженый, мудрёный.*** Если откроете авторитетные орфографические словари ОСРЯ, РОС (об используемых на канале словарях и справочниках см. здесь), то не найдете для них парных причастий. В отличие от пар крашеный (прил.) – крашенный (прич.), гашеный (прил.) – гашенный (прич.), порченый (прил.) – порченный (прич.) и др.

**Уважающие читателей СМИ,** не скупящиеся на корректоров, не допускают в этих словах ошибок: Через эти места, хоженые лишь бывалыми рыбаками и охотниками, лежит дорога. (МК, 08.08.2019)

2. Ладно, без вас знаю, что это **НЕПЕРЕХОДНЫЕ** глаголы. Так поверить, что ли?
   Пожалуй, надо спросить **у Грамоты.ру**  (поискать готовые ответы)

**Вопрос 255213.** Здравствуйте! Давно ***не езженная дорога?*** По правилам нужно так, но в словарях есть варианты: езженый, неезженый, неезженный. Езженный отсутствует. Как же быть?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка: В данном случае именно правило регулирует написание, верно: ***давно не езженная дорога.***

Интересное дело – может быть, Грамота не знает, что глагол непереходный, так как здесь зафиксирован **переход в причастие.**

3. И что же делать? Может ли слово быть причастием в каком-то частном значении? В словаре не указано... Может, **частный случай перехода** в причастие непереходного глагола?

**ЕЗЖЕНЫЙ,** - Разг. 1. Приученный к езде, объезженный. Е. конь. 2. Такой, по которому много ездили; торный (о дороге, пути). Е-ая дорога.
**НЕЕЗЖЕНЫЙ,** -ая, -ое. 1. Не приученный к езде (о лошади). Н. конь. 2. Такой, по которому **давно не ездили**, мало ездили; **ненаезженный**. Н. путь. Н-ая дорога.

4. **НЕНАЕЗЖЕННЫЙ?** Почему здесь-то две НН? Приставка, вид совершенный.  К тому же это уже **переходный** глагол.

**НАЕЗДИТЬ**, - св. что. 1. Разг. Проездить в общей сложности какое-л. время. Н. на машине пять лет. // Проехать в общей сложности какое-л. расстояние. Наездить две тысячи километров. 3. Продолжительной ездой уплотнить (какую-л. поверхность). Н. зимний путь. Дорога была плохо наезжена.

5. **Вот и подходящий частный случай**. При наличии зависимого слова прилагательное  теряет качественное значение, признак проявляется как ДЕЙСТВИЕ: ***давно не езженная дорога*** – это дорога, по которой **давно никто не ездил**.   Но это если нужно объяснить **переход в причастие**. Как думают Грамота.ру, составители ЕГЭ и вопросов по олимпиадам в настоящий момент – трудно сказать, да и мнение может меняться.
6. В чем я вижу здесь противоречие? *Незженая дорога* – это торная, заросшая травой, заброшенная, забытая, то есть качественный признак, прилагательное.  *Давно не езженная дорога* – это та, по которой **давно не ездили**, наречие **переходит**  от глагола к причастию. Графика подсказывает нам: это форма написания **для причастий** (НН, раздельное НЕ). И обозначение признака по действию.
7. С другой стороны,  в словаре для "неезженый" уже присутствует наречие "давно".  Да и графика раздельного письма с НН смотрится не лучшим образом. Мы же не говорим: **ездить (что?)**, а при раздельном написании и НН именно это читается! Получается, что даже в графическом варианте  сложно сделать выбор. **Противоречие** заложено в лексике слова «езженый", образованного от **непереходного** глагола (сравнить: красить (что?) – крашеный).
8. Как сделать выбор? Лучше уж **по Бунину** (у писателей хорошее чувство языка): Как глуха и пустынна кажется старая большая дорога, ***давно забытая и неезженая!***

**ВЫВОД.**  Поэтому никогда не отвечайте на этот вопрос, не приняв глубоко задумчивый вид. Уж очень много в нем противоречивого. А сама зачем отвечаю?  Но я как раз очень "задумчиво" отвечаю.

Comment: В общем, мы все решили, что это прилагательное? Правильно?

Comment: (1) Когда-то я решила этот вопрос для себя именно так: «неезженый» НЕ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ причастием, так как образовано от НЕПЕРЕХОДНОГО глагола (это базовая информация).  Но потом мне попалось другое оформление (как причастие, причем в каком-то авторитетном источнике, с ним приходилось считаться тоже). Слово попало под вопрос, появились сомнения. (2) Мы-то так решили, но что делать с ответом Грамоты.ру?  В ОФИЦИАЛЬНОЙ СФЕРЕ (СМИ, ЕГЭ и т.д.) всякое может быть, приходится учитывать их авторитетное мнение, да еще на текущий момент. Здесь нужна осторожность и осведомленность в  теме.

Comment: (3) Я же для себя сделала еще такой вывод.  Сочетание «ДАВНО нехоженый» противоречиво, оно нехарактерно для русской речи, писатели избегают его (об этом мы говорили в комментариях). Может быть, это вообще речевая ошибка (плеоназм)?  Зачем повторять наречие «давно»,  если оно уже заложено в значении прилагательного согласно словарю. Вот такие неожиданные «открытия»  можно для себя сделать, участвуя в интересной дискуссии, за что я благодарна и вам, и Александру.

Comment: А ссылка на этот авторитетный источник есть? Хотелось бы тоже прочитать. Нужно все мнения учесть.

Comment: Учитывайте, можете даже снять прием ответа,  я не буду в претензии.  (Обычно у нам принимают ответы,  уже задав дополнительные вопросы, это вам на будущее.)  Раньше я в форуме не участвовала, поэтому не знала, что нужны будут ссылки, так что конкретно не помню (возможно, в какой-то книге вполне приличного автора). Я вам просто пояснила, почему я заранее относилась к этим сочетаниям с сомнением.

Comment: Вы же можете использовать ссылку на Грамоту.ру  (вопрос 255213),  но я не знаю, насколько актуальна эта информация в данный момент. Или для верности задайте им вопрос еще раз. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=давно%20не&start=15

Comment: Они часто ошибаются в ответах и часто не отвечают на вопросы. Поэтому бесполезно спрашивать)

Comment: Увы, мне больше нечем вам помочь. Если считаете верным однозначный  ответ Александра, тог  должны принять его ответ. В моем случае много неопределенности, а она не всем по душе.  Грамота.ру - достаточно авторитетный источник, там специалисты как бы работают, а на наш форум особо не сошлешься, у него категория любительского.

Answer (score 0):

Я не разбирался в этой теме, но мне очень трудно представить, что «не» будет писаться слитно с отглагольными прилагательными, потому что отглагольные прилагательные не обозначают одну характеристику, как это делают прилагательные или причастия, а в сочетании с существительным они обозначают вид некого существительного со всеми свойственными ему характеристиками. Например, нельзя писать «несушеные грибы», так как это не просто грибы, которые сушили, в данном случае «сушеные» обозначает весь комплекс процедур для приготовления определенного продовольствия.
Но в данном случае, скорее всего, будет исключение, так как причастие «нехоженая» закрепилось как вид дороги и как отглагольное прилагательное именно с «не» в составе.
Опять же, я вообще не разбирался в этой теме, и написанное мною может оказаться полной чепухой.

Comment: Тоже пытаюсь разобраться в этой теме. 

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на комментарии

Перечитала еще раз принятый ответ Александра (сначала был принят  мой ответ). Там говорится, что **НЕ не влияет** на написание приставки, и это **решение** заданного вопроса.

Но, увы, это **не то правило,** которое здесь нужно применить, в данном случае  важно наличие **зависимых слов**. По правилу  **Розенталя** (авторитетный источник!) отглагольные прилагательные  обычно  в этом случае **переходят  в причастия**  (крашеный – давно не крашенный), но здесь у нас **ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ**: нет такого перехода в причастие  ввиду **непереходности** глагола «ездить».

Чтобы понять это, требуется время, нужно внимательное прочтение и ответов, и комментариев. Нужны хорошие знания – это сложная тема! Поэтому у меня к вам просьба еще раз познакомиться с правилами и традициями приемки ответов.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Принять ответ – очень ответственная задача, к тому же нет необходимости принимать каждый ответ. Нужно хорошо разобраться, понять тему, предварительно задать все вопросы, если что-то неясно. Если ответов несколько, то тем более надо хорошо подумать. Мало кто из нас принимает все ответы.

Отменять принятое решение нужно только в исключительных случаях, предварительно извинившись перед отвечающим. И уж конечно, не делать это регулярно – люди могут обидеться и вообще перестанут вам отвечать.

У участников форум есть репутация не только обозначенная баллами, но и моральная тоже. Мы внимательно присматриваемся  к новичкам и делаем свои выводы.

Не стоит, к примеру, принимать равнозначные и непротиворечивые ответы, да много всяких традиций,  желательно всё это учитывать. Я говорю вам все это исключительно из доброго отношения к вам.